# What is a good approach to save relations in repository pattern?

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I'm confused about using repository pattern when it comes to saving data. I've written discussion board so when user creates a new thread I need to save many objects (relations). Basically I need to:

1. Create new record in `topics` table
2. Create new record in `posts` table
3. Assign post's attachments
4. Add user ID to `subscribers` table (so he/she can recieve notifications about new replies)

It might look like this:

```
$topic = $topicRepository->create($request->all()); // $topic is instance of Eloquent model
$post = $postRepository->create($request->all() + ['topic_id' => $topic->id]); 

// ... save attachments etc

$url = route('topic', [$topic->id, $post->id]) . '#post' . $post->id; // build URL to new post

// I have Topic and Post model: creating notification ...
```

BUT I have feeling **I'm doing it wrong**. Shouldn't I create new method in my repository that can create new thread (add new records to `topics`, `posts` tables) and keep my controller clean?

Maybe like this?

```
// TopicRepository.php:

public function createWithPost($request)
{
    $topic = Topic::create($request);
    $post = $topic->posts()->create($request);

    // ...

    return $post;
}

// Topic.php (model):

class Topic extends Eloquent
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }
}

// Post.php (model);

class Post extends Eloquent
{
    public function topic()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Topic');
    }
}


// controller:

$post = $topicRepository->createWithPost($request->all()); // $post is instance of Eloquen model
$url = route('topic', [$post->topic()->id, $post->id]) . '#post' . $post->id; // build URL to new post
```

So questions are:

### 1) What is a good approach to save relations in repository pattern?

Should repository pattern deal with saving all relations?

### 2) Route model binding and repository pattern

Route model binding is a great feature in Laravel. Doesn't it break repository pattern rules? I mean: should we write:

```
public function index($topicId, $postId)
{
    $topic = $topicRepository->findOrFail($topicId);
    $post = $postRepository->findOrFail($postId);
}
```

instead of:

```
// Topic is a instance of Eloquent model
public function index(Topic $topic, Post $post)
{
    //
}
```

### 3) How to create or update forum thread in one controller action?

In order to DRY, I need to create one controller action that can handle creating new thread or updating existing one. How to do that using repository pattern in Laravel?

Is this a good approach?

```
public function save($topicId, $postId, Request $request)
{
    // ...
    $topicRepository->updateOrCreate($topicId, $postId, $request->all();
}
```

Thank you in advance for all opinions and tips.

Comment: Did you find an answer for #1? I'm stuck on the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

For **part 2** you could create custom middleware to do your own model binding through your repository.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CustomBindingMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure                 $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $topicId = $request->route('topic');

        if ($topicId) {
            //Get $topicRepository

            $topic = $topicRepository->findOrFail($topicId)
            $request->route()->setParameter('topic', $topic);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```